# How do I create selection state for items in a SwiftUI LazyVGrid, so it behaves like a list selection

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I am putting a grid view together in the details section of a navigation view. I would like to be able to to have a selection state on individual grid items as the user clicks them, similar to the way the List works. I don't want multiple selections, so toggle doesn't work. I would also like to customise the selection style.

```
struct Tutorials: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
}

struct ImageItems: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let icon: String
}

let allLibraries = [Tutorials(name: "All Library Items", icon: "house")]

let lessons = [Tutorials(name: "Bathroom", icon: "bathtub"),
                   Tutorials(name: "Bedroom", icon: "bed.double"),
                   Tutorials(name: "Dining Room", icon: "table.furniture"),
                   Tutorials(name: "Doors & Windows", icon: "door.left.hand.open"),
               Tutorials(name: "Kitchen", icon: "cooktop"),
               Tutorials(name: "Lighting", icon: "lamp.table"),
               Tutorials(name: "Living Room", icon: "sofa"),
               Tutorials(name: "Miscellaneous", icon: "ellipsis.circle"),
               Tutorials(name: "Office & Study", icon: "printer"),
               Tutorials(name: "Stairs", icon: "stairs"),
               Tutorials(name: "Utility Room", icon: "washer")]

let videos = [Tutorials(name: "Decoration", icon: "paintbrush"),
               Tutorials(name: "Furniture", icon: "chair"),
               Tutorials(name: "Miscellaneous", icon: "ellipsis.circle"),
              Tutorials(name: "Plants & Trees", icon: "tree"),
              Tutorials(name: "Ponds & Pools", icon: "figure.open.water.swim"),
              Tutorials(name: "Structures", icon: "door.garage.closed")]

let imageGrid = [ImageItems(name: "Decoration", icon: "paintbrush"),
              ImageItems(name: "Furniture", icon: "chair"),
              ImageItems(name: "Miscellaneous", icon: "ellipsis.circle"),
              ImageItems(name: "Plants & Trees", icon: "tree"),
              ImageItems(name: "Ponds & Pools", icon: "figure.open.water.swim"),
              ImageItems(name: "Structures", icon: "door.garage.closed"),
              ImageItems(name: "Furniture", icon: "chair"),
              ImageItems(name: "Miscellaneous", icon: "ellipsis.circle"),
              ImageItems(name: "Plants & Trees", icon: "tree"),
              ImageItems(name: "Ponds & Pools", icon: "figure.open.water")]


struct MyDisclosureStyle: DisclosureGroupStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                }
            } label: {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 15)
                    HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
                        configuration.label
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName:"chevron.right")
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(configuration.isExpanded ? 90 : 0))
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 0)
                    .padding(.bottom, 0)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            configuration.isExpanded.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 8)
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
        if configuration.isExpanded {
                    configuration.content
                    //indents the disclosure content
                        .padding(.leading, 0)
                        .padding(.top, 0)
                        .padding(.bottom, 0)
                        .disclosureGroupStyle(self)
                        
                }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    @State private var selectedList:Tutorials? = allLibraries[0]
    
    @State var selectedImage:ImageItems? = imageGrid[0]
    
    @State var expand = true
    @State var expand2 = true
    @State var expand3 = true
    @State private var isHidden = false
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                List(selection:$selectedList) {
                        ForEach(allLibraries, id: \.self) { item in
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName:item.icon)
                                    .frame(width:16, height:16, alignment: .center)
                                    .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : Color.accentColor)
                                Text(item.name)
                                    .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : nil)
                            }
                            .font(.system(size: 13,weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                            .padding(0)
                        }
                        DisclosureGroup("Home Plan Graphics", isExpanded: $expand) {
                            ForEach(lessons, id: \.self) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName:item.icon)
                                        .frame(width:16, height:16, alignment: .center)
                                        .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : Color.accentColor)
                                    Text(item.name)
                                        .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : nil)
                                }
                                .font(.system(size: 13,weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                                .padding(.top, 5)
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        .disclosureGroupStyle(MyDisclosureStyle())
                    
                    DisclosureGroup("Garden Plan Graphics", isExpanded: $expand2) {
                        ForEach(videos, id: \.self) { item in
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName:item.icon)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .frame(width:16, height:16, alignment: .center)
                                        .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : Color.accentColor)
                                    Text(item.name)
                                        .foregroundColor(self.selectedList == item ? Color.white : nil)
                                }
                                .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
                                .padding(.top, 5)
                                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                        }
                    }
                    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                    .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .disclosureGroupStyle(MyDisclosureStyle())
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 250, ideal: 250, max: 400)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 5)
        }
        
        detail: {
            
            let columns = Array(
                repeating: GridItem.init(.adaptive(minimum: 120), spacing: 20),
                count: 1)

            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    
                    ForEach(imageGrid, id: \.self) { item in
                            GridItemView(item: item)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
                .background(colorScheme == .dark ? nil : Color.white)
        }
        
    }
}

struct GridItemView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    let item: ImageItems
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                Image(systemName: item.icon)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 40, height:40, alignment: .center)
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? nil : .black)
                    .fontWeight(.light)
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                    .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? nil : .black)
            }
            .frame(width: reader.size.width, height: reader.size.height)
            .background(colorScheme == .dark ? nil : Color.white)
        }
        .frame(height:100)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(colorScheme == .dark ? .white.opacity(0.2) : .black.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 2)
        )
        
        
        
    }
    
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of irrelevant code, and also not really clear what your problem is. Can you please focus your question on specific problems and with minimal code to reproduce that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please name your structs in singular form, the selected image is **one** `ImageItem` and as there is a default value there is no need to make it optional

```
@State private var selectedImage: ImageItem = imageGrid[0]
```

And the `id` members in the structs should be constants (`let`).

`LazyVGrid` doesn't support selection, but in practice a single selection is just a special cell style.

My suggestion is to add a tap gesture to the `GridItemView` which sets `selectedImage` to the tapped grid item. Further add an `isSelected` property to `GridItemView` and style the item depending on the state

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    
     ForEach(imageGrid, id: \.self) { item in
         GridItemView(item: item, isSelected: item == selectedImage)
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedImage = item
            }
         }
     }
     .padding()
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I got an error “Extra argument isSelected in call”. Also if we can get that working, how would I style the selected state with a different border color and the non selected state with a different one? Excuse my lack of knowledge I’m learning. :)

Comment: You have to add the property `let isSelected: Bool`  in `GridItemView` and set colors, borders or whatever according to the boolean value.